# Migrating form Hostinger VPS to DigitalOcean Droplet Ubuntu 22.04

Tags: linux, ubuntu, rsync, migration

I am planning to migrate a Linux server to a new machine using rsync for a complete clone. What are the best practices to ensure a successful migration, including preserving configurations, libraries, and applications? I'm doing this because the previous developer create an app with Node but did not create docs. Additionally, what considerations should I keep in mind when assigning permissions to the cloned files and directories on the destination server? Any tips or insights would be greatly appreciated! or if you recommend a better way Im open to receive suggestions!

Edit: This files seems to be in a docker. But it's having error to initiate.